# Is there a good model of computation for real numbers?

Tags: computational-geometry, approximation, computation-models, real-numbers

/!\ I am not speaking about *int* or *float*, my question is about model of computation used to design and describe algorithms.

### The integer numbers case

Many algorithms use integers and their complexities are almost always given using both the RAM model and the big $O$ notation.

Using the RAM model allows us to add 2 integers in constant time. Assuming that the machine word size is constant, we can't assume that the codings of those integers have to be shorter than a machine word due to the big $O$ notation. Indeed this would implie that those integers are constants and this is not acceptable. For instance, *EXPTIME* algorithms with integers inputs would become constant time algorithms.

In the other hand, we can't assume that the machine words are still bigger than the input, once again some *EXPTIME* algorithms would become constant time algorithms. For instance, adding two integers whose codings are exponential in the input size.

However, we can assume that machine word size is $O(\log n)$ where $n$ is the input size, in this way we avoid previous absurdities, we can't forget more than  a $O(\log n)$ factor in the complexity. Thus, we have a good complexity theory for algorithms using only integers.

### The real numbers case

In computational geometry or in data mining, we frequently meet real coordinate spaces, but some reals are not even computable. Consequently, the $O(1)$ hypothesis for basic operators would be really monstrous, some undecidable problems would become $O(1)$. In the other hand, floating point model prohibit accuracy or is too complicated to be used if we consider accuracy.

So, what could be a good model of computation for real numbers ?

My first (and only) idea is to assume that the entropy of a real number is bounded by an input size function.

Comment: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/4529/5038,  http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/2058/5038, http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/2119/5038, http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/18585/5038,

Comment: @D.W. Thanks ! I will look at cstheory before asking, next time.
I would be not surprised if this BBS model was proved inconsistent. Do you think it's a good idea to assume that the entropy is bounded ?

Comment: Yes, there are plenty. Did you search before asking?

Comment: @DavidRicherby Indeed, when I began to write it wasn't the same question, but I solved the first one writting and this one has spawned at the same time. Thus the first question has been transformed in this one whithout break. It's why I only searched here and not in the all world wide web.